# why does rpm reinstall executes %postun after %post section

Tags: rpm, rhel, rpm-spec

I have a sample rpm spec file like

```
Name:           helloworld
Version:        2.0
Release:        2%{?dist}
Summary:        Simple Hello World rpm
License:        Internal
Source0:        helloworld-src.tar.bz2

%description

%prep
%setup -c -q -T -D -a 0

%build

%install
echo "Install command ..."

%post
echo "post command..."

%postun
echo "postun command..."


%files
%doc
%changelog
```

When I execute `rpm -i helloworld.rpm`, the output is

```
post command...
```

But when I execute `rpm --reinstall helloworld`, the output is

```
post command...
postun command...
```

Whys is this so? I was expecting `postun` to be called before `post` would be called.
Where can I find which scriplets will be called during `rpm --reinstall` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because reinstall is like an upgrade; the new one gets installed and the old one is uninstalled, triggering the `%postun`. The full sequence, from [Fedora's excellent packaging guidelines](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/Scriptlets/#ordering), shows you are hitting steps 4 and 11:

1. %pretrans of new package
2. %pre of new package
3. (package install)
4. %post of new package
5. %triggerin of other packages (set off by installing new package)
6. %triggerin of new package (if any are true)
7. %triggerun of old package (if it’s set off by uninstalling the old package)
8. %triggerun of other packages (set off by uninstalling old package)
9. %preun of old package
10. (removal of old package)
11. %postun of old package
12. %triggerpostun of old package (if it’s set off by uninstalling the old package)
13. %triggerpostun of other packages (if they’re set off by uninstalling the old package)
14. %posttrans of new package